# Create boolean mask for an array of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array with a shape (3, 3) and dtype=object whose elements are tuples of the form (str, str, float).

```
template = ('Apple', 'Orange', 5.0)
my_array = np.array([None] * 9).reshape((3,3))

for i in range(my_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(my_array.shape[1]):
        my_array[i, j] = template
```

But when I try to get a boolean mask

```
print(my_array == template)
```

The answer is all False

```
[[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]]
```

However element-wise comparison still works

```
print(my_array[0,0] == template) # This prints True
```

Why does the boolean mask return all False and how do I make it work?

P.S. I have searched for relevant topics but couldn't make use of any...

[Array of tuples in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408431/array-of-tuples-in-python)
[Restructuring Array of Tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663071/restructuring-array-of-tuples)
[Apply function to an array of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634502/apply-function-to-an-array-of-tuples)
[Filter numpy array of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726428/filter-numpy-array-of-tuples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that in Python [tuples are compared by position.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332/3568092)
So when you do

```
my_array == template
```

what you are actually doing (row-wise) is:

```
('Apple', 'Orange', 5.0) == 'Apple'
('Apple', 'Orange', 5.0) == 'Orange'
('Apple', 'Orange', 5.0) == 5.0
```

To verify that this is the case, try experimenting with the following example:

```
>>> other_array = np.array(['Apple', 'Orange', 5.0] * 3).reshape(3,3)
>>> other_array
array([['Apple', 'Orange', '5.0'],
       ['Apple', 'Orange', '5.0'],
       ['Apple', 'Orange', '5.0']], dtype='<U6')
>>> other_array == template
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

I don't know of any non-hackish way to work around this and get direct equality comparison working. If a hack suffices and your array is not too large you could try:

```
mask = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x == template,
                         my_array.flatten()))).reshape(my_array.shape)
```

or

```
mask = np.array([x == template for x in my_array.flatten()]).reshape(my_array.shape)
```

Is there a reason why you need a array of tuples? Can't you have another dimension in your array, or maybe use pandas for your categorical variables?

Comment: The elements are tuples because they come from pandas multiIndex, and the rows actually represent the sequences of multiindex values. Later I need to use np.where to find the indices which are equal to a given template. So if there is a way to get rid of tuples by, as you suggest, adding another dimension to the array, I think it will do! But is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Thanks for explanation, very helpful!

Comment: I’d suggest asking another question and giving more information on the data that you have and what exactly you want to achieve.